# Can I make a class which behaves like an immutable (float)?

Tags: python, immutability, inheritance

I have a class which calculates a moving average which could probably be improved. The size of the averaging window must be flexible.
It currently works by setting the size of the window then sending it updates thus:

```
twoday = MovingAverage(2)    # twoday.value is None
twoday = twoday.update(10)   # twoday.value is None
twoday = twoday.update(20)   # twoday.value == 15
twoday = twoday.update(30)   # twoday.value == 25
```

I thought it would be cool if it worked something more like this:

```
twoday = MovingAverage(2)    # twoday is None
twoday += 10                 # twoday is None
twoday += 20                 # twoday == 15
twoday += 30                 # twoday == 25
```

Is this stupid?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [emulate numeric types](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) by adding methods such as `__add__()`, which exactly do what you want.

Just add methods such as

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    self.update(other)
    return self

def __add__(self, other):
    return self.value + other

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.value)
```

to what you currently have.

If you want to come close to what a float does, you could add methods such as

```
def __float__(self):
    return self.value

def __radd__(self, other):
    return other + self.value
```

(the latter gives you a way to do `somevalue + twoday` and get the expected value)

and `__mul__/__rmul__`, the same with div, and so on. Your only special case is probably the `__iadd__()` mentionned above.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that too and considered it but was afraid since it would be my first time :-)... But the other problem is the accessor... retrieving the current value using the instance name "twoday" rather than "twoday.value"?

Comment: `__iadd__` is probably what you mean

Comment: @JohnMee: It depends what you mean by "retrieve". You can set your `MovingAverage` class to use its current value when printed, or converted to a string (by giving it a `__str__` method), but there's no way to make it behave like an integer in all ways, since you're giving special meaning to adding things to it. You may need to pick one thing or the other!